# React-Native can't login in build apk

Tags: android, apk, react-native

I have a problem with login in react-native app when I build it in apk. I'm not sure if the problem is the function. I use API http request for login, and on virtual device it works and I see response on the console. Can someone check please:

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            result: false,
           }
       }

    _userLogin() {
      
         let email = this.state.email;
         let password = this.state.password;
         
         if (email && password) { 
           fetch("https://URL/api/login", {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
               email: email,
               password: password,
             })
           })
           .then(async(response) => {
            let data = await response.json()
            if(response.status !== 200) {
              throw new Error(data.message)
            }
            return data})
           .then((responseData) => {
             this.renderResults(responseData)
             console.log(responseData)
           })
           .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate(IntroScreen))
           .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
           
         }
       }

       renderResults = (responseData) => {
           if(responseData){
                this.setState({
                    result: true
                })
           }
       }

       handleEmail = (text) => {
             this.setState({ email: text })
       }


       handlePassword = (text) => {
             this.setState({ password: text })
       }
```

Comment: Is your API url https or http? If it's http, you have to add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It's https and yes I put that line in AndroidManifest.xml